# Can't find variable: regeneratorRuntime (ReactNative)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator

While trying to run my project on an android emulator, the device throws this error [emulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaKWV.png). I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am still quite new to react

Answer (score 1):

firstly install babel polyfill

```
npm install --save @babel/polyfill
```

then import on top of index.js .

i mean on very top before any import

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
```

if got no answer
so

```
module.exports = {
entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./app/js"],
};
```

use it this way on your webpack.config.js

Comment: I got this error after creating a brand new project using `react-native init` with react-native: 0.61.2. The first step alone `npm install --save @babel/polyfill` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this post later, `@babel/polyfill` has been deprecated in favour of `core-js`. See https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill

If you're using >7.4.0 babel, you should be able to configure this using `@babel/env`. Set your targets in `.babelrc` (or whatever you call your babel config)

```
{
"presets": [
  [
  "@babel/env",
    {
      "targets": {
        "edge": "17",
        "firefox": "60",
        "chrome": "67",
        "safari": "11.1"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage#configuration